# How does codingame.com's monaco c# language server implementation work

Tags: c#, monaco-editor, language-server-protocol, monaco-languageserver

I'm trying to setup a monaco editor in a web project with working C#/.NET IntelliSense. The lack of available resources for this topic is a major problem for me.

By trial and error and some random code snippets from the internet, i was able to set up a working sample for lua and json, but what i actually want is a working c# prototype.

I don't want to go to deep into the details about what i already tried, because for the moment i just want to know how codinggame.com (or something similar) solved this issue on their editor. I know that there is a codinggame github repo, but there you can find only few information about it.

I found some clues about OmniSharp in their repo, which i also tried, but OmniSharp requires a "physical" directory and file structure to operate on. If they are actually using OmniSharp i would like to know how.

I thought about opening an issue in their repo, but i thought lets ask here first.

Does anyone know how it works, what they are doing?

Any help pointing me in the right direction is really appreciated.

Comment: Many of the language servers today can somehow be configured/compiled to run on WebAssembly, depending on the programming languages they are written in. For C# based language servers, you might find hints from posts like https://github.com/OmniSharp/csharp-language-server-protocol/issues/456

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick response and the WebAssembly hint. This might actually be a good solution for the moment, at least for C#. I'll give it a try in the next few days. And i guess i have to take a closer look at OmniSharps "csharp-language-server-protocol" repo and not OmniSharp itself.